# Is it possible to override default behaviour when pressing enter on textfield?

Tags: flutter-web

I am trying to override the default behaviour of a new line when pressing `enter`. I am able to catch the key event, but it still defaults to adding a new line. The idea is to execute a function on `enter` key.

Here's my code for catching the `enter` key

```
      RawKeyboardListener(
        child: EditableText(
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
          ),
          backgroundCursorColor: Colors.black,
          controller: widget.controller,
          cursorColor: Colors.black,
          focusNode: widget.focusNode,
          maxLines: null,
        ),
        focusNode: FocusNode(),
        onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
          if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter)) //Enter Key ID from keyboard
          {
            print("Enter is pressed");
          }
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you are trying to accomplish, there is a way to have a multiline `TextField` that does not create a new line on pressing enter. You could then listen in `onEditingComplete` or `onSubmitted`:

```dart
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  maxLines: null,
  onEditingComplete: () => print('Enter was probably pressed'),
)
```